# Representation of a Seq with only one element?

Tags: scala

Often I find myself passing a `Seq` with just one element to methods like this:

```
def myMethod(myList: Seq[Int]) = { ... }
```

Usually I do this like so:

```
myMethod(List(42))
```

But it occurs to me that this might not be the most elegant way, and if there's one thing about Scala that I love, it is its capability of blowing my mind by cutting down on characters used when I thought it impossible.

So, is there a shorter or more elegant representation of a single-item `Seq` than `List(42)`?

I can think of a couple worse options!

```
42 to 42
42 :: List()
```

Comment: yes, use `Seq`: `Seq(42)`

Comment: Why did I think that `Seq` was abstract? (*facepalm*)

Comment: [`Seq`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Seq) trait is, but [it's companion object](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Seq$) isn't.

Comment: use varargs in the method declaration

Comment: +1 varargs would probably be be the shortest solution if you can change the method signature without sideffects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the shortest built-in way is to just use [`Seq`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Seq$) companion object's apply and write

```
myMethod(Seq(42))
```

That apply function returns the default [`Seq`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Seq) implementation, that is A `List` and is therefore equivalent to using `List(42)`.

I'm not sure there's any `Seq` implementation with a shorter name, but you can surely implement your own or simply import `Seq` (or `List`) while aliasing the name:

```
scala> import scala.collection.{Seq => S}

scala> S(42)
res0: Seq[Int] = List(3)
```

Comment: This is the right answer. Seq(singleElement) is used extensively including in mature/well-written libraries.

Answer (score 1):

A shorter usage syntax may be obtained with this implicit,

```
implicit def SingletonSeq(i: Int) = Seq(i)
```

Hence

```
def myMethod(myList: Seq[Int]) = myList.size

myMethod(42)
res: 1
```